# iframe flash object youtube doesn't stop with sound in IE

Tags: youtube-api

If you look at this site ( http://www.dynasoft2000.com/raymeyers/ ) and click on some video's the sound won't stop.
It has been working for a few years but today it looks messed up in IE.
I am really stuck with this issue. It look likes the youtube devs screwed some things up

Can anyone reproduce this or can shine some light on this issue

Thanks for looking in

*Update solved !
It seems like an IE bug which does not destroy an iframe properly so I had to fix this by destroying the iframe before the next video start playing*

Answer (score 0):

Update solved ! It seems like an IE bug which does not destroy an iframe properly so I had to fix this by destroying the iframe before the next video start playing